# Modify program flow according to String value

Tags: .net, vb.net, variables

I am drawing a blank on how to write this code.  This is what I have right now:

```
If queststg = "Q1" Then
     q1a = vanswer
End If
If queststg = "Q2" Then
    q2a = vanswer
End If
```

And so on until I am up to Q12.  I can figure out how to get the Q# (Q and the number) to change, but I can't figure out how to get the q#a to change.  q#a variable name will always be Q# plus a.

FYI - I have a table with fields Q1, Q2, ..., Q12.  q#a tells it where to put the value vanswer (field Q#).  The above code works, but I have 12 questions so I'd have to repeat it 12 times.  There has to be an easier way.

**To clarify what I'm trying to do, here's all of the code (I only included 3 questions to save space) -**

```
    Protected Sub btnGetResult_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Dim commandtext As String
    Dim q1a, q2a, q3a As Integer

    Dim questno As String = 1 'first question number for field name

    For Each item As RepeaterItem In Repeater1.Items

        'find question
        Dim lblquestion As Label = DirectCast(item.FindControl("lblQuestion"), Label)

        Dim vanswer As String = String.Empty

        'Count q for question number

        Dim queststg As String = "Q" & questno

        'Using FindControl method to find the radiobuttons
        Dim rbnStronglyAgree As RadioButton = DirectCast(item.FindControl("rbnStronglyAgree"), RadioButton)
        Dim rbnAgree As RadioButton = DirectCast(item.FindControl("rbnAgree"), RadioButton)
        Dim rbnNeutral As RadioButton = DirectCast(item.FindControl("rbnNeutral"), RadioButton)
        Dim rbnDisagree As RadioButton = DirectCast(item.FindControl("rbnDisagree"), RadioButton)
        Dim rbnStronglyDisagree As RadioButton = DirectCast(item.FindControl("rbnStronglyDisagree"), RadioButton)

        'Check which radiobutton is checked
        If rbnStronglyAgree.Checked Then
            Dim hid1 As HiddenField = DirectCast(item.FindControl("HiddenField1"), HiddenField)
            vanswer = hid1.Value
        ElseIf rbnAgree.Checked Then
            Dim hid2 As HiddenField = DirectCast(item.FindControl("HiddenField2"), HiddenField)
            vanswer = hid2.Value
        ElseIf rbnNeutral.Checked Then
            Dim hid3 As HiddenField = DirectCast(item.FindControl("HiddenField3"), HiddenField)
            vanswer = hid3.Value
        ElseIf rbnDisagree.Checked Then
            Dim hid4 As HiddenField = DirectCast(item.FindControl("HiddenField4"), HiddenField)
            vanswer = hid4.Value
        ElseIf rbnStronglyDisagree.Checked Then
            Dim hid5 As HiddenField = DirectCast(item.FindControl("HiddenField5"), HiddenField)
            vanswer = hid5.Value
        End If

        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("<br />Q: {0} <br />A: {1} <br />", lblquestion.Text, vanswer))


        **If queststg = "Q1" Then
            q1a = vanswer
        End If
        If queststg = "Q2" Then
            q2a = vanswer
        End If
        If queststg = "Q3" Then
            q3a = vanswer
        End If**

        questno = questno + 1
    Next

    Using sqlconnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=WillSQL\ict2;Initial Catalog=StudCourseEval;Integrated Security=SSPI")

        commandtext = "Insert into tblQuestionnaire (Q1, Q2, Q3) values (@vq1a, @vq2a, @vq3a)"

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(commandtext, sqlconnection)

        sqlconnection.Open()

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vq1a", q1a)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vq2a", q2a)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vq3a", q3a)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        sqlconnection.Close()

    End Using

    lblMSG.Text = sb.ToString()
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You need an easier way than this??

Comment: Why don't you use an array or a dictionary?

Comment: What kind of application is this? Can you provide more information about the expected result?

Comment: And when Q13 comes around... what then? Consider refactoring to support a more abstract approach. My 2 cents.

Comment: I revised my question - I already have the looping for the number covered.  It's a question and answer website, where the answers are radio buttons.  In my SQL database, each question is a different field.  So, field Q1 can have an answer 1 thru 5 depending on the radio button clicked.  The code above works great - I'm just trying to see if there's another way to do it because what if there's 100 questions.  Right now, I'm just concentrating on the q#a values.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, i don't find it difficult and to repeat this 12 times is not that much. But for what it's worth, you could store it in a dictionary:

```
Dim qDict = new Dictionary(Of String, String)
qDict.Add("Q1", q1a)
qDict.Add("Q2", q2a)
' ....
qDict.Add("Q12", q12a)
```

You neeed to initialize this only once. Then you can always access it via key:

```
qDict(queststg) = vanswer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim answers(11) As String ' should this be an integer? Other? It's not clear from the question
Dim QuestionIndex As Integer = Integer.Parse(queststg.SubString(1)) - 1
answers(QuestionIndex) = vanswer
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a matrix, ie. QA(12,2).  Then you can loop through using the loop index to reference each question and answer.

```
For i = 1 to 12
   If queststg = QA(i,1) Then
       q1a = QA(i,2)
   End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Select Case queststg
Case "Q1"
q1a - vanswer
Case "Q2"
q2a = vanswer
end select
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have missed the point of your question entirely as I didn't find it that clear, but I have assumed that you have a list of questions and answers;

so you should consider having a question and an answer located in the same data structure e.g. a class:

```
Public Class QA
    Public Property Question As String
    Public Property Answer As String
    Public Sub New(question As String, answer As String)
        Me.Question = question
        Me.Answer = answer
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then you can create a list of questions and answers like so:

```
Dim qaList As New List(of QA)
qaList.Add(New QA("This is question 1", "This is the answer to question 1"))
'etc.
```

Then you can access this list by Index

```
For i as Integer = 0 to qaList.Count -1
    Debug.Writeline("Question #" & i.ToString() & " is " & 
        qaList(i).Question & " the answer is " & qaList(i).Answer)
Next
```

That should make your life a lot simpler

Comment: I think this might be correct - I'm just having a hard time putting it into my code.  I'm going to edit my question to include the whole code.  Can you please look at it?  Thanks!  (I know it's not that hard to just type it 12 times, but what if there's 100 questions?)  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

While I like @TimSchmelter 's answer better, someone should mention that the standard way to handle something like this in VB is with the `Select Case` structure:

```
    Select Case queststg
        Case "Q1"
            q1a = vanswer
        Case "Q2"
            q1b = vanswer
        Case "Q3"
            q1c = vanswer
    End Select
```